# Its time taking

Tags: python-3.x

TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

```
def get_score_of_calorie(text):
    actual = getActualValue(text)
    predicted = float(get_calorie(text)[0])
    #accuracy_score = metrics.accuracy_score(predicted,actual)
    accuracy_score = predicted/actual
    return accuracy_score
```

Comment: This is my code follows : actual = getActualValue(text)
    predicted = float(get_calorie(text)[0])
    #accuracy_score = metrics.accuracy_score(predicted,actual)
    accuracy_score = predicted/actual
    return accuracy_score

Comment: What is the datatype of `actual`? is it a string still?

Comment: Please change your question to be fully illustrating your problem. E.g. what exactly is "text" and what is "getActualValue". Your question cannot me answered otherwise.

Comment: @JonSG actual is a string

Comment: If `getActualValue` returns a string, I think you likely want to cast it to a `float()` as well just like `get_calorie()[0]`